# Return value 3221225477 occurs when I use pointer to struct pointer in code

Tags: c, pointer-to-pointer

What is wrong in my code below?

There are no errors or warnings when I compile it by Dev C++ compiler. But after I run my program there is execution error and following return value text:

> Process exited after 5.1 seconds with return value 3221225477
>   Press any key to continue . . .

Any idea what is wrong?

When I use debug feature, error occurs in that line:

```
printf("Value of (*pointerToMyOwnStructPointer)->a = %d\n", (*pointerToMyOwnStructPointer)->a);
```

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
}myIntegers_t;

int main (void)
{
    myIntegers_t *myOwnStructPointer = NULL;
    myIntegers_t **pointerToMyOwnStructPointer = NULL;

    myOwnStructPointer = (myIntegers_t*)malloc(sizeof(myIntegers_t));

    if (myOwnStructPointer > 0)
    {   
        myOwnStructPointer->a = 2;
        myOwnStructPointer->b = 8;

        printf("Value of myOwnStructPointer->a = %d\n", myOwnStructPointer->a);
        printf("Value of myOwnStructPointer->b = %d\n", myOwnStructPointer->b);

        pointerToMyOwnStructPointer = (myIntegers_t**)myOwnStructPointer;

        printf("\n");
        printf("Value of (*pointerToMyOwnStructPointer)->a = %d\n", (*pointerToMyOwnStructPointer)->a);
        printf("Value of (*pointerToMyOwnStructPointer)->b = %d\n", (*pointerToMyOwnStructPointer)->b);  
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: You can only compare pointers to related pointers (i.e. two pointersthat are both pointing to the same array) or to `NULL`. And if you compare with `NULL` you can only check for equality or inequality, not any other relational operator.

Comment: `if (myOwnStructPointer > 0)` causes undefined behaviour. It should be `if (myOwnStructPointer != 0)`

Answer (score 3):

in your code,

```
 pointerToMyOwnStructPointer = (myIntegers_t**)myOwnStructPointer;
```

is very wrong. You need to change that to

```
pointerToMyOwnStructPointer = &myOwnStructPointer;
```

to get the expected behaviour.

To elaborate,

- `myOwnStructPointer` is a pointer-to-type.
- `pointerToMyOwnStructPointer` is a pointer-to-pointer-to type.

they are not *equivalent*. *Just* because they are both pointers, you cannot simply *cast* value of one type to another and expect that to work. The cast is wrong (*and not even required*). So,

- Do not cast
- Enable compiler warnings.

Most of the time, your compiler will save you, through a warning, at least.

---

Note: Please [see why not to cast](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Answer (score 1):

There *would* be errors or warnings if you didn't have that cast in the assignment

```
pointerToMyOwnStructPointer = (myIntegers_t**)myOwnStructPointer;
```

That's because `myOwnStructPointer` is a pointer to your structure, but `pointerToMyOwnStructPointer` is a pointer to a pointer to your structure, and those two types are totally incompatible.

The compiler will interpret it like this:

```
+-----------------------------+    +--------------+    +--------+
| pointerToMyOwnStructPointer | -> | some address | -> | struct |
+-----------------------------+    +--------------+    +--------+
```

So when you do your assignment and then use `pointerToMyOwnStructPointer` it lead to *undefined behavior* since it's not pointing to a pointer.

---

The lesson here is that you should almost *never* insert type-casting to solve compiler errors or warnings, the errors and warnings are there for a reason, and warnings often tell you that you are doing something suspect that might lead to undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Only an improvement suggestion

Also, the correct `malloc` way of allocation would be

```
myIntegers_t * myOwnStructPointer = malloc(sizeof(myIntegers_t));
if (myOwnStructPointer == NULL)
    return 1;

. . .    // else do something with myOwnStructPointer;
```

Answer (score 0):

This was my original code and now it is working after I added one '&' mark. Thanks a lot of your support!!

Any comments about this code?  I think there is cast for the return value of malloc function... is that problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define OK 1
#define FAILURE 0

typedef struct{
    int a;
    int b;
}myIntegers_t;

void * open(void);
int close(void ** pointerToMyOwnStructPointer );

void main(void)
{
    void * myVoidParameter;

    if(myVoidParameter = open())
    {
        printf("\n\nPORT OPENED SUCCESSFULLY!!\n\n");

        myIntegers_t ** pointerToMyVoidParameter = (myIntegers_t**)&myVoidParameter;

        printf("\n");
        printf("Value of pointerToMyVoidParameter->a = %d\n", (*pointerToMyVoidParameter)->a);
        printf("Value of pointerToMyVoidParameter->b = %d\n", (*pointerToMyVoidParameter)->b);

        if(close(&myVoidParameter))
        {
            printf("\n\nPORT CLOSED SUCCESSFULLY!!\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\n\nFAILURE IN PORT CLOSING!!!\n");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nFAILURE IN PORT OPENING!!!\n");
    }
}

void * open(void){

    myIntegers_t *myOwnStructPointer = (myIntegers_t*)malloc(sizeof(myIntegers_t));

    if (myOwnStructPointer)
    {   
        myOwnStructPointer->a = 2;
        myOwnStructPointer->b = 8;

        printf("\n");
        printf("Value of myOwnStructPointer->a = %d\n", myOwnStructPointer->a);
        printf("Value of myOwnStructPointer->b = %d\n", myOwnStructPointer->b);

        return myOwnStructPointer;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

int close(void ** pointerToMyOwnStructPointer ){
    int result = OK;
    myIntegers_t ** descriptor = (myIntegers_t**)pointerToMyOwnStructPointer;

    if(descriptor == NULL || *descriptor == NULL)
    {
        return FAILURE;
    }

    printf("\n");
    printf("Value of descriptor->a = %d\n", (*descriptor)->a);
    printf("Value of descriptor->b = %d\n", (*descriptor)->b);


    (*descriptor)->a = 0;
    (*descriptor)->b = 0;
    free((void*)*descriptor);
    *pointerToMyOwnStructPointer = NULL;

    return result;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your new question.

You should always cast malloc in c++ and never cast malloc in c, as already stated by Shreevardhan and Sourav Ghosh.

All of your void* are in fact myIntegers_t*, so make them myIntegers_t*. It both benefits the reader, but also makes it possible for the compiler to spot errors.

All of your void** are in fact myIntegers_t**. See above.

Unless the contents of a and b is secret, you don't have to make them 0 before freeing. And free doesn't need its argument to be cast to a void*, since void* are compatible with all pointers. It only needs the pointer to have been made by malloc, calloc or realloc.

I don't think the extra descriptor helps anything, except perhaps readability, but then just rename pointerToMyOwnStructPointer.